# Half-Adder Exercise

Tags: binary

My exercise is the following:

```
Make a circuit which outputs X^3 of two bit input of X.
Use the lowest number of HALF ADDERS as you can.
```

I don't really understand how to compute $X^3$ with half adders.

Any hints or any help is appreciated.

Edit: the exercise is meant for $X^3$ rather than $X \oplus 3$.

Comment: I suggest making a table (I forget what their called in Circuit Design) that shows the expected outputs from the possible inputs of X.

Comment: You also might have more luck if you ask your question on [Electronics.SE].

Comment: Isn't the obvious thing to start with a multiplication circuit?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume `X^3` is $X \oplus 3$. Since a half adder is a XOR gate and an AND gate, you would just use 2 half adders with the other input being `11`, the binary notation of 3.

If you really mean X cubed, you would require a multiplier (or more simply a lookup table) with conditional addition. This could be done with the AND gates of the half adder, but I doubt your exercise would ask for this.

Comment: my excercise does ask me for x cubed. Thank you for the answer, though I do mean x cubed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to compute 2 bits cubed, then you are trying to compute:

$$\begin{align}
bXY^3 &= bA\,BCDE \\ \hline
b00^3 &= b0\,0000 \\
b01^3 &= b0\,0001 \\
b10^3 &= b0\,0100 \\
b11^3 &= b1\,1011 \\
\end{align}$$

A half adder lets you compute a carry bit and a sum bit:

$$\text{CarryOut} = \text{Maj2}(A,B,\text{CarryIn})$$
$$\text{sum} = A \text{ xor } B \text{ xor } \text{CarryIn}$$

So using the above two functions, you want to create the above table.  I'll use $\bot$ for zero or ground.

$$\begin{align}
E &= Y \\
D &= \text{Maj2}(X, Y, \bot) \\
C &= \text{Maj2}(X,Y,\bot) \text{ xor } X \text{ xor } \bot \\
B &= \text{Maj2}(X,Y,\bot) \\
A &= \text{Maj2}(X,Y,\bot) 
\end{align}$$

That's two half adders and some wiring.  Good luck.

Comment: thank you. I will try.

Comment: @Alan: And you might want to use Logisim if you're not already using it, to save you the trouble of duplicating and connecting physical circuits.

Comment: I think you meant $X,Y$ instead of $A,B$ in various places, and also $C = X \text{ and } ( X \text{ xor } Y )$

Comment: @user21820 thanks I'll correct, I changed variables as I posted